# Securing API Keys in Flutter: Tried flutter build apk --obfuscate, but still visible in JADX

Tags: android, flutter, security, obfuscation, api-key

I'm currently working on a Flutter project that heavily relies on the Yandex MapKit package for its mapping features. In order to utilize these map functionalities, I'm required to provide an API key within the **MainActivity.kt** file. To bolster security, I've adhered to best practices by storing the API key in a dedicated **key.properties** file and referencing it within the **build.gradle** file.

However, even after implementing these measures, I've discovered that my API key remains visible in the decompiled code when I used JADX to decompile the APK. In an attempt to heighten security further, I also employed Flutter's obfuscation feature by running
`flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=/<project-name>/<directory>`

Despite these efforts, my API key continues to be accessible in the decompiled APK.

I'm committed to ensuring the utmost security for my API key. I'm seeking guidance on effective strategies to safeguard API keys in a Flutter Android project, especially when utilizing external packages like Yandex MapKit. How can I ensure that my API key isn't easily extractable from the decompiled code, even after enabling code obfuscation? Are there additional steps I should take or alternative methods to consider to ensure the security of my API key?

For reference, I utilized the JADX decompiler (https://github.com/skylot/jadx) to examine the decompiled code.

Thank you immensely for your invaluable insights and support!

Comment: Please read https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate#limitations. It is common that API keys can be extracted from APK files. Developers how don't want to store API keys in plain text often use self-developed system for encrypting the keys before injecting them into the code. Of course that required decryption before you can use the keys.

Comment: @Robert thank you for the response. Yes, I've read it. It's unfortunate that hiding them isn't as straightforward as mentioned in the documentation. I overlooked that part. It turns out even moving the keys to a separate file like key.properties is done to avoid publishing them on GitHub.

I'll now explore methods for encrypting these keys. If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thanks again!